# Substituindo DatePickerAndroid e TimePickerAndroid por DateTimePicker, porém não consigo utilizar

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, mobile, datetime

Estou fazendo um projeto de um curso que comprei, porém em certa aula é utilizado o `DatePickerAndroid` e `TimePickerAndroid`, que foram descontinuados (inclusive o TimePicker nem exite mais).

O código era o seguinte:

```
export default function DateTimeInputAndroid({type}){

    const [datetime, setDateTime] = useState();

    async function selectDataOrHour(){
        if(type == 'date'){
            const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
                mode: 'calendar'
            })
        if (action == DatePickerAndroid.dateSetAction)
        setDateTime(`${day} - ${month} - ${year}`);
        } else {
            const {action, hour, minute} = await TimePickerAndroid.open({
                is24Hour: true
            });

            if (action != TimePickerAndroid.dismissedAction)
            setDateTime(`${hour}:${minute}`);
        }
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={selectDataOrHour}>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} 
            placeholder={type =='date' ? 'Clique aqui para definir a data' : 'Clique aqui para definir a hora'}
            editable={false}
            value={datetime}/>
            <Image style={styles.iconTextInput} 
            source={type =='date'? iconCalendar : iconClock} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Segui as instruções da documentação do `DateTimePicker`, e tentei reconstruir o código, porém o mesmo não está funcionando como deveria (ao clicar no touchable, abrir o calendário/relógio). Ficou desta maneira:

```
export default function DateTimeInputAndroid({type}){

    const [datetime, setDateTime] = useState();

    setDate = (event, date) => {
        if (date !== undefined) {
          setDateTime(format(new Date(date), 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
        }
      };

      setTime = (event, date) => {
        if (date !== undefined) {
            setDateTime(format(new Date(date), 'HH:mm'));
        }
      };

    async function selectDataOrHour(){
        if(type == 'date'){
        <DateTimePicker mode='date' value={new Date()} onChange={setDate()} display='default'/>
        } else {
        <DateTimePicker is24Hour={true} mode='time' value={new Date()} onChange={setTime()}/>
        }
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={selectDataOrHour}>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} 
            placeholder={type =='date' ? 'Clique aqui para definir a data' : 'Clique aqui para definir a hora'}
            editable={false}
            value={datetime}/>
            <Image style={styles.iconTextInput} 
            source={type =='date'? iconCalendar : iconClock} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Não consegui identificar o que fiz de incorreto, visto que se o DateTimePicker for criado dentro do return, ele executa assim que o componente é carregado normalmente.